# ObservableCollection<Entity>.Property does not update UI after change

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Consignments}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConsignment}"
            x:Name="dataGridConsignments" 
            Margin="10,47,10,9.6"
            IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            clr:Commands.DataGridDoubleClickCommand="{Binding DataGridDoubleClick}">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ConsignmentId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created" Binding="{Binding CreatedDate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding TotalWeight, StringFormat=N2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And in my `ViewModel`:

```
private ObservableCollection<Consignment> consignments;
public ObservableCollection<Consignment> Consignments { get { return consignments; } set { consignments = value; OnPropertyChanged("Consignments"); } }
```

Now, I want to remove an item from `DataGrid` and also update the Ids of those items so tha there are no gaps (Ids should read 1,2,3,4...), so I have this command:

```
private ICommand removeConsignment;
public ICommand RemoveConsignment
{
    get
    {
        return removeConsignment
            ?? (removeConsignment = new ActionCommand(() =>
            {
                var c = SelectedConsignment;
                StandardDatabase.Commands.RemoveConsignment(c.Id);
                Consignments = new ObservableCollection<Consignment>(db.Consignments.ToList());
            }));
    }
}
```

`Commands.RemoveConsignment` updates everything in db, but the UI stays the same (e.g. if I delete item 2, the IDs read 1, 3, 4...).

- As you can see I tried adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `ObersvableCollection` itself, but this did not work.
- I think I can probably add this to the `ConsignmentId` property in the model itself, but I don't think that is advisable?
- I even recreate the collection directly from the Db, but somehow it still doesn't work.. even after navigating to different pages andcoming back
- Another option would be to wrap `Consignment` in a `ConsignmentViewModel` object - which I have had some success with before - but my understanding is that following MVVM then I should just be manipulating the `Consignment` entites themselves from the VM? (as using further VMs in `PageConsignmentsViewModel` would mean I am using 2 viewmodels for a single view)

Would really appreciate it if anyone can provide a suggestion

**Commands.RemoveConsignment()**

```
public static void RemoveConsignment(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var consignment = db.Consignments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        db.Consignments.Remove(consignment);

        // Reset consignmentIds
        for (int i = consignment.ConsignmentId ; i < db.Consignments.Count(); i++)
        {
            var c = db.Consignments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ConsignmentId == i + 1);
            c.ConsignmentId = c.ConsignmentId - 1;
            db.Entry(c).CurrentValues.SetValues(c);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Consignment.cs**

```
public class Consignment : EntityBase
{
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    public virtual int ConsignmentId { get; set; }

    public Consignment()
    {
        Packages = new HashSet<Package>();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public double TotalWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return Packages.ToList().Sum(p => p.PartQuantities.Sum(pq => pq.UnitWeight * pq.Quantity));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I am a little confused by the wording as it relates to the expectations around the Ids

Comment: @Nkosi In the method `Commands.RemoveConsignment` I am re-assigning those Ids (note that `ConsignmentId is **not** the primary key - its just the name of the consignment), and I can see the changes reflected in the db - I added the code to my question

Comment: Something looks odd with how you are assigning the ids.  What is suppose to be happenign there

Comment: I want the `DataGrid` to show Consignments with `ConsignmentId`s 1,2,3, etc - if I delete consignment with `ConsignmentId`=2, then `ConsignmentId`=3 should have its `ConsignmentId` set to 2, thereby preventing any gaps (the new grid will read 1,2). It works as expected in the db but its just the view which I am having trouble with

Comment: Is `ConsignmentId` part of Db entity or just for visuals in the UI?

Comment: @Nkosi `ConsignmentId` is an Entity property - I added `Consignment.cs` code to my question.

Comment: @Nkosi Perhaps I should just be using a `ObservableCollection<ConsignmentViewModel>` instead

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework caches unless you turn of change tracking.

If you read a table's worth of data, it is changed in the database and then you read that table's content again it gives you what it has in memory rather than going back to the database.

If you want change tracking then the simplest way round this is to dispose your dbcontext and use a new one.

You could read more here:

http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/